# RIGHT OUTER JOIN and WHERE when there are matching rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, outer-join

I am having issues understanding the RIGHT OUTER JOIN logic.

We have two tables of data - `Process` and `Resource`

```
Process                             Resource    
ProcessID   ResourceID  Date        ResourceID  ResourceName
1           1           01/01/2015  1           Resource 1
2           1           02/01/2015  2           Resource 2
3           2           02/01/2015
```

We created the SELECT statement

```
SELECT *
FROM Process P
RIGHT OUTER JOIN Resource R ON P.ResourceID = R.ResourceID
WHERE P.Date = '2015-01-01'
```

And the expected results are

```
ProcessID   ResourceID  Date        ResourceID  ResourceName    
1           1           01/01/2015  1           Resource 1  
NULL        NULL        NULL        2           Resource 2  <-- This row is not returned
```

However we only receive one row - we want each resource for each process that we select, with null values returned from the process table where they dont match.

If we change the query and remove the row with ProcessID of 3 the query returns both resources, but our example has a join on a row we have not selected, so seems not to be returned.

```
SELECT *
FROM Process P
RIGHT OUTER JOIN Resource R ON P.ResourceID = R.ResourceID
WHERE P.Date = '2015-01-01' OR P.Date IS NULL
```

How can we make the query return the expected results with the data shown above?  What are we missing?

Comment: To humans LEFT JOIN is so much easier to understand. You have "main table left join additional/optional-table". RIGHT JOIN is the other way, first optional data table, then main table.

Comment: Basically it has to exist on the right but not the left. So you've told it that you want any records with resourceID from Resource and to show any data from Process that matches it. First one did, second one didn't because it didn't have a date of 01/01/2015 so ResourceID of 2 existed but with no match. Hope that helps make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a `right outer join`, if you want to filter on the first table, the condition needs to go in the `on` clause.  Otherwise, the `join` becomes an `inner join`.

However, I encourage you to use `left outer join`.  Most people find it easier to follow the logic of "keep everything in the first table" rather than "keep everything in the last table".  A similar rule holds, but for the second table rather than the first:

```
SELECT *
FROM Resource R LEFT OUTER JOIN
     Process P
     ON P.ResourceID = R.ResourceID AND P.Date = '2015-01-01';
```

Comment: Do you have any more documentation on how it 'becomes an inner join'?

Comment: The P.Date is null and null = '2015-01-01' is false, that way it works much like an inner join